# Save virtual scroll position

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid with lots of data and more than 100 pages. I need to save the scroll position before leaving the page with scroll.

That I should do to save the grid state according to business requirements, so: I save page number and element Id(to select it in the grid).But thats all is useless when scroll position can`t be restored.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RegistryInspectionTaskDto>()
          .Name("grid")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(o => o.LocalPlannedStartDate).ClientTemplate("#=DateTimeHelper.GetSimpleClientString(LocalPlannedStartDate)#").Format("{0:g}").Title(InspectionTaskResources.DateLabelText).Width(180);
              columns.Bound(o => o.VehicleNumber).Title(InspectionTaskResources.VinLabelText).Width(187);
              columns.Bound(o => o.TypeName).Title(InspectionTaskResources.TypeLabelText).Width(100);
              columns.Bound(o => o.Id).Hidden(true);
              columns.Bound(o => o.StatusName).ClientTemplate("#=list.GetStatusColumnTemplate(StatusId, StatusName)#").Title(InspectionTaskResources.StatusLabelText);
          })
          .Sortable()
          .Selectable(x=>x.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
          .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Virtual(true))             
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .PageSize(100)
              .Sort(x=>x.Add("LocalPlannedStartDate").Descending())
              .Read(read => read.Action("GetInspectionTasks", "InspectionTasks").Data("GetFilterParameters"))
          ))
```

I have read a lot of kendo documentation/ but I`ve found nothing. Do you have any idea, how to solve that problem? Any help appreciates

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier if you store the current grid row instead of the scroll position. Then you can use the kendo select method. Here is how: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/select . Still if you need to scroll you can use the select row class and use jQuery to move the scroll. `scrollTo = $('.saveIcon');`

Comment: The problem is that this is not constant data source, so it`s impossible to select the element from undefined page and to scroll to selected row/ If i'm not right, please, ket me know

Comment: If I understood correctly, you can use the UID. Rows in the Grid have a data-uid attribute. This attribute is tied to the DataSource item corresponding to that row. You can also pass them thru a parameter from different pages. Or stored on a cookie and reuse it later

Comment: But UID changes every time i reload the page with grid. Also, i didn`t know the way, how to find element in datasource by Id(only when this element is displayed), and i think that its impossible to scroll to desired element in grid

Comment: @OleksaKachmarskyi please take a look to the example and also the API reference. https://www.telerik.com/forums/set-grid-uid-to-datasource-primary-id

Comment: @cjlmartins I've already tried that method, but get() function doesn`t work

Comment: @OleksaKachmarskyi I found this https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-scroll-selected-row but unfortunately is just for the jQuery component. Just in case you can use it in your project.

Comment: @cjlmartins, yeah, thanks, but that works only if we have static dataSource, not dymanic. And not only for jquery component) thanks for idea, now i have more possibilities for trying to solve that problem